# Android Custom ListView. Showing different row layout after clicking on it

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm newbie in android studio and I face this problem for two hours. Was looking for some olution in other answers and other websites without any result.
I've got fragment with ListView which contain some tasks to do. All tasks are stored in Database and I'm using Custom CursorAdapter to represent these data.
I have got two different row_layouts, one is with just image, title of task and deadline. Second one has the same stuff, two buttons and description of single task. User after clicking on single row in ListView should see these additional buttons and TextView. I've tried to to by myself but i get lost.

Here is adapter code:

```
public class ChallengeAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private int position = 1;

public static class ChallengeViewHolder {

    ImageView challengeIcon;
    TextView challengeTitle;
    TextView challengeDeadline;
    TextView challengeDescription;
    Button bFinished;
    Button bRemove;

}

public static final int[] challengeIcons = {

        R.drawable.brain_icon,
        R.drawable.book_icon,
        R.drawable.workout_icon
};

public ChallengeAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

public void selectedItem(int position) {

    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {


    ChallengeViewHolder holder = new ChallengeViewHolder();

    if(this.position == cursor.getPosition()) {

        View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.extended_row_challenge_list, parent, false);
        holder.challengeIcon = (ImageView) view2.findViewById(R.id.ChallengeIconExtended);
        holder.challengeTitle = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.ChallengeTitleExtended);
        holder.challengeDeadline = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.ChallengeDeadlineExtended);
        holder.challengeDescription = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.ChallengeDescriptionExtended);
        holder.bFinished = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.bFinished);
        holder.bRemove = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.bRemove);

        view2.setTag(holder);

        return view2;
    }


    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_challenge_list, parent, false);
    holder.challengeIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ChallengeIcon);
    holder.challengeTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ChallengeTitle);
    holder.challengeDeadline = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ChallengeDeadline);

    view.setTag(holder);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ChallengeViewHolder holder = (ChallengeViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.challengeTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title")));
    holder.challengeDeadline.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("deadline")));
    holder.challengeIcon.setImageResource(challengeIcons[cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("icon_id"))]);
}
```

}

Here comes code of single row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/normalRowLayout"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ChallengeIcon"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ChallengeTitle"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="HERE COMES THE BASS!"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ChallengeIcon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="#3696E4"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ChallengeDeadline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="28 days 6 hours 7 minutes 16 secunds"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ChallengeIcon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ChallengeTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    />
```

and extended row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/extendedRowLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ChallengeIconExtended"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ChallengeTitleExtended"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="HERE COMES THE BASS!"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ChallengeIconExtended"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="#3696E4"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ChallengeDescriptionExtended"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ChallengeIconExtended"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ChallengeTitleExtended"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="description description description description description description description description description description description description vdescription description description description description description description"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ChallengeDeadlineExtended"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="28 days 6 hours 7 minutes 16 secunds"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ChallengeIconExtended"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ChallengeDescriptionExtended"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="#FD1103"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bFinished"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ChallengeDeadlineExtended"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Finished"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedbuttongreen"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bRemove"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ChallengeDeadlineExtended"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Remove"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedbuttonblue"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    />
```

Also adding Photo how it looks like when i set position in adapter to 1:

[image]

Comment: Use only the extended row with the extra views set visibility to `View.GONE`. When the user click, simply change those visibilities to `View.VISIBLE` (don't forget to reset to `View.GONE` inside `bindView`

Comment: ok i will check your solution. Thank you in advance!